# How to refresh fragment B from fragment A?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have an Activity contains two fragments displayed as two tab, tab 1 is fragment A and tab 2 is fragment B. Tab 1 show list of all items and Tab 2 show list of favorite. When I choose an item in Tab 1 and click "Add to favorite", this item will be inserted into SQLite database, and Tab 2 will display data from this database.

The problem is two tabs will be loaded at the same time I go to this activity, after I "Add to favorite", this item will not be displayed in tab 2 until I go back and open this activity again. Is there anyway to refresh list in tab 2 right after I click "Add to favorite" in tab 1.

I am not good at English, hope this question clearly for you enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check if the Fragment is visible to the user. you can try this:

```
public class FavoritesTab extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
      // Refresh your fragment here
    }
  }
```

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

> How to refresh fragment B from fragment A?

You can use this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) to communicate between 2 fragments. It use observable pattern, communicate through Activity containing 2 Fragments (fragment A and fragment B).

If you want something simpler, you can use [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), very easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a **BroadcastReceiver** or **communicate the two fragments through the activity**.

**Communicating the two fragments through the activity:**

When you add an item in Fragment A, you call a method in the Host activity that will call a method in Fragment B to refresh the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways.

**1. through Activity**

You have Fragment A and Fragment B in your activity.
Also you have your activity in Fragment A and Fragment B.

MainActivity.java

```
FragmentA A;
FragmentB B;

private void updateB(){
   if(B!= null){
      B.refresh();
   }
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mainActivity = getActivity();
}
private void addFavorite(){
   //add item to DB
   //reload Fragment A
   mainActivity.updateB();
}
```

FragmentB.java

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mainActivity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    mActivity.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
private void refresh(){
   ...
}
```

**2. using broadcast**

FragmentB.java

```
private MyReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(MyReceiver.ACTION);
    mActivity.registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}


public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION = "com.xxxx.test";
    public static final String TYPE_REFRESH = "TYPE_REFRESH";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
        if (type.equals(TYPE_REFRESH)) {
            refresh();
        } 
    }
}

public static void sendBroadcastForRefresh(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION);
    intent.putExtra("type", TYPE_REFRESH);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
private void addFavorite(){
    ....
    FragmentB.sendBroadcastForRefresh(mContext);
}
```

**3. recreate fragment**

```
    FragmentManager fManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
    B= FragmentB.newInstance();
    fTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_b_id, B, "B Tag"); // <-- this one will recreate your fragment
    fTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); //or fTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

just override onResume method and show favorites again in onResume so every time that you open fragment B onResume method will start and it will refresh the content.
put it in your fragment class:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    //refresh content 
    //show favorite items here again
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call setTargetFragment() when you start the Fragment B from A.

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance();
fragmentB.setTargetFragment(FragmentA.this, REQUEST_REFRESH_CODE);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentB).commit();
```

and then when you want to refresh fragment A from B, you can call the following code:

```
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(
                getTargetRequestCode(),
                Activity.RESULT_OK,
                new Intent()
);
```

and refresh A fragment from the onActivityResult() method in your fragment A:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==REQUEST_REFRESH_CODE && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        refreshYourFragmentHere();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:You can use **RxBus**.

Solution 2:

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {

    AFragment a;
    BFragment b;

    public void c() {
        //init fragment
        a.setOnItemClickListener(b);
    }

}


class AFragment extends Fragment {

    OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }
}


class BFragment extends Fragment implements AFragment.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {
        //refresh
    }

}
```